# usb.core.USBError: Resource busy

Tags: python, arduino, udev

I'm currently trying to build a USB communication path between an Arduino UNO board and my PC. Thus, I've first written the following code for the Arduino, which passed through the compilation and was uploaded to the board:

```
int led =13;
char password = 'a';

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output
  // open the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // check for incoming serial data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read incoming serial data:
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    // check if it matches
    if (inChar == password){
        for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        blink();
    }
  }  
}

void blink() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Then I wrote the following python code:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x2341, idProduct=0x0043) # Arduino SA Uno R3

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

# set the active configuration. With no arguments, the first
# configuration will be the active one
dev.set_configuration()

# get an endpoint instance
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]

ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)

#assert ep is not None

# write the data
ep.write('a')
```

To activate the access to the USB port of my Arduino board, I created the following UDEV rules file, saved it under /etc/udev/rules.d/, and rebooted my system:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", MODE="0666", GROUP="root", OWNER="xxxx"
```

Now, as I run my python code, I always get this error:

```
runfile('/home/xxxx/Data/dev/python/usb_test.py', wdir=r'/home/xxxx/Data/dev/python')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/bhan/Data/dev/python/usb_test.py", line 20, in <module>
dev.set_configuration()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 799, in set_configuration
self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 128, in managed_set_configuration
self.backend.set_configuration(self.handle, cfg.bConfigurationValue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 730, in set_configuration
_check(self.lib.libusb_set_configuration(dev_handle.handle, config_value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 552, in _check
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 16] Resource busy
```

It seems that the Arduino driver or something else has occupied the device access, but I have no idea how to close or disable it. How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: I've resolved this problem by removing the driver module:

sudo rmmod cdc-acm

Comment: how do you add the driver module back again?